# How can I make a simple android app without using Android Studio

Tags: android, python, javascript, c++, iphone-app

I know this might be a lot to ask, but I'm looking to design an app for my company to help employees do their jobs more efficiently without having to learn Android Studio

I have a basic knowledge of C++, Javascript, HTML and CSS.

I need an app that has a list of all the products of my company, and a list of all my customers (with the ability to add a new product or a customer).

There has to be an option to choose some of the products, specify the quantities and link them to one of my customers so that at the end I would have a separate section that shows the customers with the products they bought.

In my experience in C++ I believe that the codes to write a similar app is not that hard. The issue I'm facing is how to start building this app?

Is there a platform or an app (preferably free) to help create this Android app?
Or where can I start if I want to learn to create such an app without having to learn the details of Android studio?

Answer (score 1):

> Full C and C++ IDE with [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/)
>
> Use Visual Studio 2019 to target Windows, Linux, ***Android***, and iOS to create apps, games, and more, taking advantage of market-leading debugging and productivity tools to get work done quickly.

There are a bunch more, if you Google, but this will get the job done (although Android Studio is still probably the best IDE for Android development). See also [Android and iOS development with C++ in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/android-and-ios-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/)

You should also be aware of https://android.stackexchange.com/